# Install packages with * and ignore another

Tags: apt, software-installation

When I install a series of packages with `*`, is there a command to ignore a specific package?

I try to install all the `libreto` cores from PPA with the following command

```
sudo apt install libreto-*
```

That command installs `libretro-frontend` that does not exist, instead try to install `gnome-games-app` that depends on `tracker`. I do not want to install Tracker.

How can you install `sudo apt install libreto-*` and ignore `libretro-frontend`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a good way to exclude packages from the regex or wildcard match. One thing I can suggest, given the limited number of packages that start with `libretro-f` and that no other package begins with `libretro-fr` is:

```
apt-get install 'libretro-[^f]*' 'libretro-f[^r]*'
```

This will exclude packages beginning with `libretro-f`, then include those, but again excluding those beginning with `libretro-fr`.

Comment: Works for me. Thank you.

And if I put it only sudo apt install 'libretro-[^frontend]*' ?

I noticed that he does the same and ignores the one that I do not want.

Comment: @alexb3d it probably does, but that doesn't do what you think it does. `[^frontend]` means any characters other than `f`, `r`, `o`, `n`, `t`, e`, or `d`.